# Multiselect - many to many - C#, EF savechanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Following on from this line with using multiselect:
[mvc 4 MultiSelect list & EF many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15462062/mvc-4-multiselect-list-ef-many-to-many)

When I try to save all the changes back to the context they don't save, only tht blog data not the categories.

The only way out has been to save the Bind data first, create a new context and then save the list.

Any suggestion on an alternative?

Below is the controller code that is not saving the Categories but it saving the Blog data from the post:

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id,Blog blog, int[] selectedCategories)
{

    blog.Categorys = new List<Category>(); //adding because coming back null

    //loop though and add the items posted
    foreach (var item in selectedCategories)
    {
    Category c = db.Categorys.Find(item);
    blog.Categorys.Add(c);
    }

    db.Blogs.Attach(blog);
    db.Entry(blog).State = EntityState.Modified;
    db.SaveChanges();

return View("Test", blog);
}
```

Values are added to the blog Model ok but are not saved to the database.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not showing any changes to the categories. You are finding a category that already exists in the database and creating a blog -> category association. Depending on your relationship mapping, the dbcontext would not detect that any changes need to be made to the categories table.